# Folder/files interface in XAML, proper control choice?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, drag-and-drop, treeview

Here is interface that I want to achieve:

[image]

Basically, this is 1 level deep structure with folders and files inside folders.
Screenshot that you see is my attempt doing this with `ItemsControl` and `ListBox` inside `ItemsControl`

Things that I need:

1. Folders not selectable. No interactions, just showing them.
2. Only one file can be "selected" at time
3. Files can be dragged and dropped from one folder to another
4. Everything done in MVVM

Right now with the way I do it - multiple ListBoxes therefore focus on multiple elements which is bad.

I don't know yet how to achieve drag/drop.

I'm thinking about `TreeView` control but unsure how is that going to work.

I'm looking at pointers on how to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `TreeView`, two `TreeViewItems` styles "FolderLevelStyle" and "FileLevelStyle". Extract the defaukt style from Blend for both of them.

In "FolderLevelStyle", remove all triggers for `IsMouseOver` and `IsSelected` properties. Also, set `ItemContainerStyle` to be "FileLevelStyle".

This will give you points 1 and 2.

[in "FolderLevelStyle"] You can also set `IsExpanded` to `True` and collapse the `ToggleButton` in the control template (including removing all triggers that affect that button) - this will not allow the user to "close" folders.

Regarding Drag-And-Drop, there are several approaches to this. Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx). See how you can integrate it into your MVVM schema. I'd gravitate towards creating a `Behavior` (or attached behavior) that will be set on the root panel in the `DataTemplate` for the file item.

Comment: Thanks! This is along lines how I think about it. I guess I will have to create one object `FolderOrFileItem` that will contain List<FolderOrFileItem> and use some switches to determine which one to use? How would I `bind` proper style depending on item? Should I use DataTemplateSelector for this?

Comment: I got it working to some degree but I don't know how to apply different styles depending on bound item. Any suggestion?

Comment: In your case, you don't have to look at it as "choose a style by type", instead see it as "first level - style 1; second level - style 2". So, considering the naming from the answer above, in "FolderLevelStyle" add `<Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{DynamicResource FileLevelStyle}"/>`

Comment: Tried this way - no go. It doesn't pickup FileLevelStyle. Silverlight doesn't support DynamicResource, I used StaticResource, maybe thats why?

Comment: Sorry, forgot it was SL. Make sure that "FileLevelStyle" is written in the same ResourceDictionary as "FolderLevelStyle" and above it in the XAML.